# 日付を表示するdate関数の返り値を反映させたい

Tags: javascript

javascript,htmlについて質問です。
以下のコードに日付を表示するdate関数の返り値を反映させたいです。

```
$("#board").prepend("<li class='board'>"+data.value.message+"<button id='button'></button></li>");
```

---

date関数（コンソールで表示の確認が取れています）

```
function date(){
    myTbl = new Array("日","月","火","水","木","金","土");
    myD = new Date();
    myYear = myD.getFullYear();
    myMonth = myD.getMonth() + 1;
    myDate = myD.getDate();
    myDay = myD.getDay();
    myHours = myD.getHours();
    myMinutes = myD.getMinutes();
    mySeconds = myD.getSeconds();
    myMess1 = myYear + "年" + myMonth + "月" + myDate + "日";
    myMess2 = myTbl[myDay] + "曜日";
    myMess3 = myHours + "時" + myMinutes + "分" + mySeconds + "秒";
    myMess = myMess1 + " " + myMess2 + " " + myMess3;
    return myMess;
}

date(); 
console.log(date());
```

Answer (score 1):

反映したい場所に `+` 演算子で結合すればよいです。
`button`要素の中に入れたいのであれば、以下になります。

```
$("#board").prepend("<li class='board'>"+data.value.message+"<button id='button'>" + date() + "</button></li>");
```